# Radiobutton / Checkbox stays checked while changing state

Tags: wpf, checkbox, radio-button, checked, expression-blend-4

I'm building a WPF-application with Expression Blend 4 and I've got a problem.

When I check a radiobutton or checkbox and I want to Log Out (a state that hides all the checkboxes and slides in another screen) and I log in again I still see the radiobutton checked.

Is there a way to terminate all 'checked-state' when I press a normal button to go to another state?

Thx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It might be that I don't fully understand your question, but shouldn't you address this directly from code-behind in an event related to your logging-out?